# What is the number of quadratic residues in $Z_{11^4}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I am stuck on this question.

We know there exists (p-1)/2 number of quadratic residues in $Z_{p}$, how about in $Z_{p^a}$? Can we approach it by Hensel's Theorem?

For example, What is the number of quadratic residues in $Z_{11^4}$?

Comment: For an odd prime $p$, we have $\mathbb Z_{p^n}^\times\cong\mathbb Z_{p^{n-1}}\times\mathbb Z_{p-1}$. The quadratic residues correspond to the subgroup $\mathbb Z_{p^{n-1}}\times2\mathbb Z_{p-1}$, which has size $(p-1)p^{n-1}/2$.

Comment: In other words, $\mathbb Z_{p^n}^\times$ is cyclic of even order, so half its elements are quadratic residues.

Comment: I understand that right now. Thank u soo much for the help!

Comment: I just got one more question. Followed by this, suppose there exists $Z_{p_{1}^a * p_{2}^b}$, where $p_{1} ≠ p_{2}$ and $a≠b$, then what is the size of the subgroup (i.e. the number of quadratic residues) for $Z_{p_{1}^a*p_{2}^b}$ ?

Comment: Hint: by the Chinese Remainder Theorem $\mathbb Z_{p_1^ap_2^b}\cong\mathbb Z_{p_1^a}\times\mathbb Z_{p_2^b}$, so the group of units is $\mathbb Z_{p_1^ap_2^b}^\times\cong\mathbb Z_{p_1^a}^\times\times\mathbb Z_{p_2^b}^\times$.